# Sifr 3 a:hover not active outside text

Tags: sifr

I have an unordered list with links. The links have display:block; in the css so the hover will also have effect in the padding surrounding the links. I replace the list-items with sIFR 3. In the sifr-config.js I specify a hover color for the text but this only works on the text itself, not on the padding surrounding the text. Is there a solution for this problem?
I got it working for the padding on the left side of the text by adding margin-left:'25' in the config for .sIFR-root but margin-right doesn't have the same effect. Help greatly appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say based on your question, but if you replace the individual list items, the entire list item will be a sIFR link. If you want more space around the text you should do this within the Flash movie rather than in CSS. You can use the `tuneWidth`, `tuneHeight`, `offsetTop` and `offsetLeft` parameters for this.